# Connection issues when trying to connect to a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, authentication, permissions, ssms

I'm trying to connect to a remote SQL Server database. It's being hosted on another server within the network at my workplace, but I keep getting an error when trying to connect while being logged in under a specific Windows (AD) account.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio from my local server. I tried logging in with account "x". When specifying the connection string I'm using a SQL Server authenticated user. This is when I get the error below:

[image]

I logged in with a different account "y" to the server and attempted the database connection again (with the same SQL Server authenticated user), and it worked.

Why would I be able to connect under one Windows account and not the other (from the same server) when I'm trying to connect with a SQL Server authenticated user?
Could this be that the Windows account is not part of the correct administrator group?

Any thoughts or insights are appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried/are you able to turn on login auditing?

Comment: check your network on that windows and the firewall or antivirus

Comment: @XingzhouLiu How would I do that?  I don't have a lot of experience dealing with MS SQL databases

Comment: @EidMorsy wouldn't it affect the other account as well?

Comment: There are several ways to listen to login auditing events, do you have server admin privileges and what version are you using?

Comment: @XingzhouLiu I do have server admin privileges and the server that's hosting the DB is using SQL Server 2016.  Note that I am using SQL Server 2012 to try to connect to it.

Comment: If you can restart the server, right click the instance in SSMS : properties. Then go to the security screen and check what to log (success, fails, or both). Then restart the server. The results are written to the instance error log. If you can't restart, there are some more complicated ways.

Comment: @XingzhouLiu I'm not able to restart the server.  We have data being sent back and forth between client computers.